# Bass Clef in Math text

Tags: math-mode, symbols, stix, musixtex

I'd like to write a **Bass Clef** in a Math Text. I know math packages and `musixtex`. My goal is to write something like that:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{stix}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{musixtex}


\title{Chiave di Basso prova}
\author{PUCK}
\date{\today}

\begin{document}

\maketitle

\section{Introduction}

Let $\bassclef\coloneqq\bigl\{\bassclef,\le\bigr\}$ a Partial Ordered Set.
\end{document}
```

Why insted of `\bassclef` Overleaf outputs me an "$I$"?
I hope this question is clear. Thank you so much

Answer (score 2):

You can use `\text` to access the text mode symbol font, although you might want to raise it slightly, depending what you want it to look like  (`\raisebox` might help)

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{stix}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{musixtex}


\title{Chiave di Basso prova}
\author{PUCK}
\date{\today}

\begin{document}

\maketitle

\section{Introduction}

Let $\text{\bassclef}\coloneqq\bigl\{\text{\bassclef},\le\bigr\}$ a Partial Ordered Set.
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thank you very much David Carlisle! Now I'd like that `\bassclef` is smaller and centered in text. Is it possible? (Must I create a New Answer or You can edit your answer?)

Comment: Already corrected, thanks again for help!

Answer (score 1):

You can use directly the `musix` font, instead of loading the whole package. The font needs to be slightly rescaled and the symbol has to be moved up, because it extends below the baseline with strange height and depth.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{stix2}
\usepackage{mathtools}

\DeclareFontFamily{U}{musix}{}
\DeclareFontShape{U}{musix}{m}{n}{<-> s*[0.85] musix11}{}
\newcommand{\mathbassclef}{%
  \text{%
    % as high as an uppercase letter
    \vphantom{A}%
    % the clef extends below the baseline, so we raise and smash it
    \raisebox{.55\height}[0pt][0pt]{\usefont{U}{musix}{m}{n}\symbol{73}}%
  }%
}


\begin{document}

Let $\mathbassclef\coloneqq\bigl\{\mathbassclef,\le\bigr\}$
be a partially ordered set.

\end{document}
```

[image]

Do you think that your readers will know what it is and how to call it?

#### ADDITION

Since barbara beeton's wishes are my commands, here's a version that does what she asked for in comments.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{stix2}
\usepackage{mathtools}

\DeclareFontFamily{U}{musix}{}
\DeclareFontShape{U}{musix}{m}{n}{<-> s*[1.01] musix11}{}
\newcommand{\mathbassclef}{%
  \text{%
    % as high as an uppercase letter
    \vphantom{O,}%
    % the clef extends below the baseline, so we raise and smash it
    \raisebox{.412\height}[0pt][0pt]{\usefont{U}{musix}{m}{n}\symbol{73}}%
  }%
}


\begin{document}

Let $\mathbassclef\coloneqq\bigl\{\mathbassclef,\le\bigr\}$ 
be a partially ordered set.

\fboxsep=0pt\fboxrule=0.1pt

\fbox{,O$\mathbassclef$}\fbox{O}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Of course the parameters need to be changed to accompany different fonts.

Comment: Scaling is one thing, but I think this looks unnatural without a slight descender, at least as low as the bottom of the comma.

Comment: @barbarabeeton Done as you wished. On the other hand, the bass clef stays fully in the staff.

Comment: Oh, *much* nicer.  Now it really looks like a legitimate symbol.  (Haven't any idea what it might mean though.)